# The probability that the product of 100 die rolls $\le$ $a^{100}$ for $1 < a < 6$

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose that a fair $6$ sided die is rolled 100 times. Let $X_i$ be the value
obtained on the $i$th roll. Compute an approximation for
$ P\left(\prod X_i \le a^{100}\right)$ for $1 < a < 6$.

I'm thinking about using Central Limit Theorem but not sure how. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- To use the central limit theorem, you need to translate the product into a sum.  There is a natural way of doing this
- You will need to calculate the mean and variance or standard deviation for these new random variables
- You can then use the normal distribution (or, if you prefer, the log-normal distribution) to approximate your inequality

Comment: I think I'm confused with how to translate the product into a sum. Could you give some advice on this? Thank you!

Comment: $\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)$

Comment: Ohhhh I got it. Thanks so much!